# In C++20, the get<>() function inside <tuple> is no longer in namespace std. Why?

Tags: c++, get, c++20, global-namespace

The following code does not compile in C++17 but from C++20 on:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

int main() {

    auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    get<0>(t); // no std:: required!

    return 0;
}
```

Since this works with both g++ and clang++ and both `-stdlib=libc++` and `-stdlib=libstdc++` and even in msvc with `/std:c++20`, I wonder whether this is a "feature". What is the rationale behind this? Is there more pollution to the global namespace besides this?

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate mark, as ADL is only half of the explanation... But since there is already an excellent answer, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::get` is found by argument-dependent lookup (ADL), because `t` has a type that is a specialization of the class template `std::tuple` which is located in the same namespace scope as the `std::get` overload you want to use. This is behavior that has always existed in C++ and is fundamental to making operator overloading work, as well as other customizable function calls like `swap`.

The reason it fails in C++17 has nothing to do with whether `std::get` is found, but rather with the rules that determine whether or not the `<` following `get` is the less-than operator or the start of an template argument list. Before C++20, if the unqualified name before the `<` wasn't found at all by usual unqualified (non-ADL) lookup, the program was ill-formed. Since C++20 it is assumed to introduce a template argument list in this situation.

For example, if you add a function template named `get`, regardless of signature, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void get();
```

into your global namespace scope, then `<` will also be assumed to introduce a template argument list because this function template is found for `get` by usual unqualified lookup, even in C++17. Then ADL applies to the call as usual (this has always worked this way in every C++ edition) and `std::get` will be found as candidate as well.